# when to escape entities in string resources?

Tags: android, xml, android-resources

I'm confused by some of the [escaping rules of Android string resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling), particularly when it comes to HTML.

Under normal XML encoding rules, consider the following encodings -

a. *"Foo & Bar"*

```
<string name="a">Foo &amp; Bar</string>
```

b. *"Foo &amp; Bar"*

```
<string name="b">Foo &amp;amp; Bar</string>
```

c. *"Foo <b>&amp;</b> Bar"*

```
<string name="c">Foo &lt;b&gt;&amp;amp;&lt;/b&gt; Bar</string>
```

---

But as the bold tag is **allowed as a part of the XML DOM**, apparently you can do -

```
<string name="d">Foo <b>&amp;</b> Bar</string>
```

This is where I get confused, because it's as if a string can be either HTML **or** plain text without any explicit indication of intent.

So my question, using a case that combines the above:

To encode the html string *"Foo &amp; Bar <b>&amp; Baz</b>"* - are the rules for the first ampersand different from the second? Do I do this? -

```
<string name="e">Foo &amp; Bar <b>&amp; Baz</b></string>
```

or this? -

```
<string name="f">Foo &amp;amp; Bar <b>&amp; Baz</b></string>
```

"f" seems nuts, but if the answer is "e" then how does a decoder know not to decode the ampersand like it does in example "a"? Just because the string has child elements?

Please note I am not asking because I'm encoding strings, I'm asking because I'm **parsing them**. I'm not interested in solutions like "use CDATA" - I'm trying to understand the rules.

Answer (score -1):

To display

<string name="f">Foo &amp; Bar <b>&amp; Baz</b></string>

use:

```
 <string name="f">Foo &amp;amp; Bar <b>&amp;amp; Baz</b></string>;
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. I'm asking about the content of a <string> element, not how to escape the whole XML source.

Comment: OK, I edited the answer. you still need to use &amp;amp; in font:bold, &amp; only displays ampersand sign '&'. Tested with Eclipse.